# Choose month from drop down using selenium controlled Mozilla on python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, mozilla

I want to make an automated Gmail account creator. For some reason, I am not being able to web driver to click on the month and choose a month to proceed with the creation.I'm using an earlier version of selenium(2.4) and Firefox(25) because of having problems with gecko driver.

```
<label id="month-label" class="month">

    <span id="BirthMonth" class=" form-error" aria-invalid="true">
        <div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button jfk-select" role="listbox" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" title="Birthday" aria-activedescendant=":0">
            <div id=":0" class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-caption" role="option" aria-setsize="12" aria-posinset="0"> … </div>
            <div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-dropdown" aria-hidden="true"> … </div>
        </div>
        <input id="HiddenBirthMonth" type="hidden" name="BirthMonth"></input>
    </span>

</label>
```

I have filled all of the earlier fields which didn't require a dropdown.

```
birthelem2=(browser.find_element_by_id('BirthMonth'))
birthelem2.click()
month=browser.find_elements_by_class_name('goog-menuitem-content')
month[0].click()
```

I expect it to choose a month(January)

Comment: share HTML code for the same, and exception stack trace if any.

Comment: I updated the question, There is no stack trace. It returns None when I try to get the element of birthday month